# how to inject context to HttpModule

Tags: nestjs

I want inject `context.heanders` to Httpmodule when it register.how?

nestjs 6.0

i create a global Module like below, i want add context.header in this place

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.register({
      timeout: 20000,
     // (how to get context.header in this place )
      // headers: {
      //   'x-sec-profile': '281567',
      //   'accessToken': 'f647e353790fd5c54dbd8c06be4575a58f369476a569c71a',
      // },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AxiosModule {}
```

this is cats.resolver.ts

```
@Resolver(Cat)
export class CatsResolver {
  constructor(private readonly catsService: CatsService) {}
  @Query(returns => Cat,  { name: 'cat' })
  async findDetail(@Args('id') id: number, @Context('headers') headers) {
    console.log(arguments.length)
    return await this.catsService.findDetail(id)
  }
}
```

use cats.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) { }

  async findDetail(id) {
    const a = await this.httpService.get('https://yuangong.com/api/contract-web/contract/contract-detail',
    {params: { contractId: 1000320 } }).toPromise()
    return {
      contractId: a.data.data.id,
    }
  }
}
```